# Unable to identify the errors in this program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Am doing mapreduce for the following code. When i run this Job every thing works fine. But the output shows 0 0. I suspect this may be due to the TryparseInt() method which i QUICKFIXED as it was undefined previously.Initially there was no method for the TryparseInt(). so i created one, Can any one check whether the code is correct expecially the TryParseInt Method and tell me any suggetion to run this program successfully.

input looks like :

Thanks in Advance

---

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;


public class MaxPubYear {

public static class MaxPubYearMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable , Text, IntWritable,Text>
    {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value , Context context)

                throws IOException, InterruptedException
                {
            String delim = "\t";
            Text valtosend = new Text();
            String tokens[] = value.toString().split(delim);
            if (tokens.length == 2)
            {
                valtosend.set(tokens[0] + ";"+ tokens[1]);
                context.write(new IntWritable(1), valtosend);
            }

                }      
    }


public static class MaxPubYearReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable ,Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {

        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int maxiValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            String maxiYear = "";
            for(Text value:values)          {
                String token[] = value.toString().split(";");
                if(token.length == 2 && TryParseInt(token[1]).intValue()> maxiValue)
                {
                    maxiValue = TryParseInt(token[1]);
                    maxiYear = token[0];
                }
            }
            context.write(new Text(maxiYear), new IntWritable(maxiValue));
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job Job = new Job(conf, "Maximum Publication year");
            Job.setJarByClass(MaxPubYear.class);

            Job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            Job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            Job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
            Job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            Job.setMapperClass(MaxPubYearMapper.class);              
            Job.setReducerClass(MaxPubYearReducer.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(Job,new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(Job,new Path(args[1]));
            System.exit(Job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);                

        }

public static Integer TryParseInt(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return(0);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The errors mean exactly what they say: for the three 'could not be resolved to a type' errors you probaobly forgot to import the right classes. Error 2 simply means there is no method `TryParseInt(String)` in the class `MaxPubYear.MaxPubYearReducer` you have to create one there.

Comment: No, SO is not for _get this done for me_ questios. The errors are already self-explaining and with my awnser you should be able to fix them yourself.